# How to Get a List of Running Processes

Tags: dart

I know that Dart is able to run a process with dart:io package and Process.run, but, How can I use Dart to get the list of the currently OS running processes?

Comment: There are no such thing in the standard SDK so I will suggest you find the command on your OS to do thing you want and execute that command from Dart with Process.run and parse the output.